# speeding up waiting notifcations using BLE with bluepy in python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) to get data from a sensor equipped with a Bluetooth low energy device in Python. The sensor is a device I designed myself. Therefore, I have access to the processing on board of the sensor.

It now takes 2 seconds to get data from the sensor. On the sensor, the data collection process takes only 200 ms. This delay occurs 'waiting for notification' (1.7 seconds). I have pasted my whole Bluetooth communication class below. However, in brief code works as follows:

1. write a string to the sensor over Bluetooth (the sensor parses this to see what kind of data it should return)
2. wait for notification using `while self.peripheral.waitForNotifications`.
3. read the data (this is fast << 1 ms).

So, it's this step 2 that takes time (although the sensor starts sending back after about 200 ms).

Does anybody know whether it might be possible to speed step 2 up?

```
import struct
import bluepy.btle as btle
import numpy
import time


class ReadDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = b''

    def reset(self):
        self.data = b''

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        self.data = self.data + data

    @property
    def data_length(self):
        return len(self.data)


class myHC08:
    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.mac = '34:14:B5:50:22:ED'
        self.write_service_id = 4
        self.write_service = None
        self.delegate = ReadDelegate()
        self.peripheral = None

    def print_output(self, message):
        print('HC08: %s' % message)

    def connect(self):
        self.peripheral = btle.Peripheral(self.mac)
        self.peripheral.withDelegate(self.delegate)
        s = self.write_service_id
        services = self.peripheral.getServices()
        self.write_service = self.peripheral.getServiceByUUID(list(services)[s].uuid)

    def wait_for_notification(self, time_out=5):
        start = time.time()
        while self.peripheral.waitForNotifications(1):
            waiting = time.time() - start
            if waiting > time_out: return False, False
        waiting = time.time() - start
        return True, waiting

    def wait_for_data(self, min_bytes, time_out=5):
        start = time.time()
        while self.delegate.data_length < min_bytes:
            waiting = time.time() - start
            if waiting > time_out: return False, False
        waiting = time.time() - start
        return True, waiting

    def write(self, message, min_bytes, unpack_string=False):
        if self.verbose: self.print_output('Writing %s' % message)
        self.delegate.reset()
        c = self.write_service.getCharacteristics()[0]
        c.write(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
        self.verbose: print("HC08 Receiving %i bytes" % min_bytes)

        if self.verbose: self.print_output('Waiting for notification')
        success, duration = self.wait_for_notification()
        if not success: return False
        if self.verbose: self.print_output('Duration: %.10f' % duration)

        if self.verbose: self.print_output('Waiting for data')
        success, duration = self.wait_for_data(min_bytes=min_bytes)
        if not success: return False
        if self.verbose: self.print_output('Duration: %.10f' % duration)

        received = self.delegate.data
        if unpack_string:
            received = struct.unpack(unpack_string, received)
            received = numpy.array(received)
        return received

    def write_robust(self, message, min_bytes, unpack_string=False, max_retry=3):
        for attempt in range(max_retry):
            if self.verbose: self.print_output('Attempt %i out of %i' % (attempt, max_retry))
            result = self.write(message, min_bytes, unpack_string)
            if result is not False: return result
            if not result: self.reconnect()
        if not result: raise ('Error could not get data in %i attempts.' % max_retry)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.peripheral.disconnect()

    def reconnect(self):
        self.print_output('Reconnecting')
        for x in range(5): self.disconnect()
        self.connect()
```

Comment: what does `waitForNotifications` does?

Comment: It looks like self.peripheral.waitForNotifications(1) is actively waiting one second for a notification to arrive. I looked at the documentation, this is actually the right way to do this in bluepy. Since the method only takes a timeout value in seconds this seems to be the "fastest" way you can get notifications using bluepy... Maybe someone with experience in bluepy can help you finding another solution or you need to look for another, faster ble library

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the notifications with the `bluetoothctl` command line tool? Was the performance when you used that?